# how to download dynamic file name from url

Tags: c#

I want to download the file from url link that is always changing in file name like today's date. I tried regex for filename but it is in the url. for example, the real url is http://www.sunrise.com.au/web/file/item141112_plain.xls in "LIVEHTTPHeaders", but the link from the web browser is http://www.sunrise.com.au/mailout/simple_excel.asp.I am downloading the file from C# console application using Webclient.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue, why do you need regex? You're trying to construct a filename and pass it to WebClient?

Comment: We cant see the sunrise link, you need permission to view it. Hence can you show us the LIVEHTTPHeader and your code that doesn't work and what needs to be done to make it work

Comment: You should include some code of what you have tried already and an example of what is wrong with the result you are currently getting.

Comment: For confidential issues, I cannot upload  the real url links. I will upload  the current code later. Thanks.